# Saving web pages containing scripts

Tags: flash, javascript

Is there an easy way to save entire websites or isolated web pages containing Flash or Javascript?

Comment: does `CTRL+S` work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a single answer to this question.

Obviously, web pages containing JS or Flash are meant to be dynamic, the code contained in the JS/Flash may not work when saved.

However, in general, yes, there are ways of doing this.

[HTTRACK](http://www.httrack.com/) is probably the best way. Though wget ([wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)) would also work (wget is available in most Linux distros).

HTTRACK tries to rename most links so that they point to the local copy of the resource and so JS/Flash files *may* still work.